# Can I apply must_use to a function result?

Tags: rust

I have a function that returns a `f64`. I'd like to ensure that the output from this function is used, rather than just ignored. Is there any way to do this?

The return type is not used for error handling so wrapping it in a `Result` or `Option` doesn't really make sense.

I'd like something similar to this:

```
#[must_use]
fn calculate_the_thing(number: f64) -> f64 {
    number * 2.0
}
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since Rust 1.27 [#[must_use] attribute can be used on functions](https://blog.rust-lang.org/2018/06/21/Rust-1.27.html#must_use-on-functions)

```rust
#[must_use]
fn calculate_the_thing(number: f64) -> f64 {
    number * 2.0
}

fn main() {
    calculate_the_thing(4); // warning: unused return value of `calculate_the_thing ` which must be used

    let _ = calculate_the_thing(4); // (no warning)
}
```

---

In older versions, `#[must_use]` only applied to types, not individual values.

One alternative is to define a simple wrapper type that is `#[must_use]`:

```rust
#[must_use = "this value should be used (extract with .0)"]
pub struct MustUse<T>(pub T);
```

Your function can then return `MustUse<f64>`, and users will get a warning if they write `calculate_the_thing(12.3)`, even suggesting the right way to get the thing they want: `let x = calculate_the_thing(12.3).0;`. [For instance](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=75a7e99c1b4446a8a0b4076a83d6b3b7&version=stable&backtrace=0&run=1):

```rust
fn calculate_the_thing(number: f64) -> MustUse<f64> {
    MustUse(number * 2.0)
}

fn main() {
    calculate_the_thing(12.3); // whoops
    
    let x = calculate_the_thing(12.3).0;
    println!("{}", x);
}
```

```
warning: unused `MustUse` which must be used: this value should be used (extract with .0)
 --> src/main.rs:9:5
  |
9 |     calculate_the_thing(12.3); // whoops
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: #[warn(unused_must_use)] on by default
```

Comment: *extract with .0* — that's a little bit of slickness that I did not expect. Very cool!

Comment: It would be nice if the number of bytes written, returned from [`Write::write`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/trait.Write.html#tymethod.write), was `must_use`, not just the `Result` it's wrapped in.  Ignoring this, and assuming all the data was written, is likely to be an intermittent bug.

Comment: Sadness.  RFC 886 would have been fantastic--(what I was looking for, actually).  :(

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you can, thanks to [RFC 1940](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1940-must-use-functions.md) and available starting in Rust 1.27. Your original code works as-is:

```
#[must_use]
fn calculate_the_thing(number: f64) -> f64 {
    number * 2.0
}

fn main() {
    calculate_the_thing(21.0);
}
```

```
warning: unused return value of `calculate_the_thing` which must be used
 --> src/main.rs:7:5
  |
7 |     calculate_the_thing(21.0);
  |     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: #[warn(unused_must_use)] on by default

    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.71s
     Running `target/debug/playground`
```

Comment: Do you know any reason why this isn't the default behavior for functions to be annotated with the must_use annotation? Swift's behavior is reversed: we must explicitly annotate the function with @discardableResult when not wanting to do anything with the return type of the function (else: warning). This looks more error-free than Rust's approach. When creating a function with a return type, I think it is likely that the creator of the function wants the caller of the function to do something with the results. Adding the must_use annotation everything is a lot of noise and pain to maintain.

Comment: When nothing is returned, nothing is expected. When returning a value and it isn't assigned to anything, I think it's weird that Rust things: 'O, nothing to see' and a annotation must be added to produce any sort of warning. I can not imagine any case in which the Rust way of dealing with not-assigned values is more error-free than Swift's style (which is: always a warning when not assigning a value when calling a function but you can explicitly opt out by adding @discardableResult (this is pretty rare from what I know))

Comment: I think it's better this way around. Simply because the caller has the freedom to discard something he doesn't need. Also the author of the function makes the conscious decision that the value is this important to use that a warning is appropriate. For example a lazy function that only does something when the result is used in some way. In this case the author knows that and marks the function or type as must_use. An add function on the other hand might return a confirmation boolean the user might not need. He doesn't need to think about whether the value is used or not its up to the user.